# Simple Relay Control with Arduino

Tags: matlab, arduino, switch-statement, controls

I am new to coding for Arduino. I have done Java and Matlab in the past.

I have designed a simple replay circuit as seen here:
 [image]

I assume it is set up right, but if not please let me know.

I basically need simple code to just trigger the relay on and off for intervals of 1 second indefinitely or until I just disconnect the power.

Any help would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: You're probably better off asking at http://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the Blink example that comes with Arduino IDE. Connect the Relay output control to pin 13 (your yellow wire) and you have it.

```
   /*
  Blink
  Turns on an LED on for one second, then off for one second, repeatedly.

  This example code is in the public domain.
 */

// Pin 13 has an LED connected on most Arduino boards.
// give it a name:
int led = 13;

// the setup routine runs once when you press reset:
void setup() {                
  // initialize the digital pin as an output.
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);     
}

// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(1000);               // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(1000);               // wait for a second
}
```

Even better would be to use the blink without delay example